# EventEmitter ordering events

Tags: javascript, node.js

Since the meaning of "order" is broad, let me explain the case I am interested in.

A fairly common pattern (good or bad):

```
client = net.connect(...)
client.on('connect', () => {
  client.removeAllListeners('error');
  client.on('error', err => {
    ... // process IO errors
  });
  ...
});
client.on('error', err => {
  ... // process connection failures
});
```

The way I understand this works, it is possible that a `connect` event is emitted, and later an IO `error` is emitted. But is there a guarantee at `EventEmitter` level that handling of events acts like a barrier (in proper concurrent programming speech).

For example, in this case I would like to see a guarantee that the `connect` handler removes the `error` handler set up for connection errors only, and a new handler set up for IO errors only. But will the new event listener list be taken into consideration only during the next tick? I want to be sure that mutually excluded handlers in program order (concurrent programming speech: "removeAllListeners" and "on('error')" appear executed in that order, therefore it is impossible for both handlers to receive the same event) are also mutually excluded in synchronization order (concurrent programming speech: events "connect", "removeAllListeners", "on(`error`)" and "IO error" are part of a total synchronization order).

The question is about event emitter in general, not how the connection processing works, because a similar pattern can be seen in other places - for example, the same connection reused to process different transactions, and need to bind an `error` handler for the duration of individual transactions, but cannot afford to overlap the handlers, or to handle events after the transaction moved on.

Is there such a guarantee in `EventEmitter`? Otherwise, many patterns like above really need to be coded much more defensively.

Answer (score 0):

None of the `EventEmitter` methods defer until the next tick or anything, they all do all of their work at the time they are called.

So doing `client.removeAllListeners('error');` will immediately remove all event handlers for the `error` event.

Comment: But there is also the case of "event queue" having more than one event queued up. Is there a guarantee how exactly they are queued up? For example, at the time the event is emitted, its handlers are queued up - that would mean that if several events manage to be emitted in one tick, the handlers will be enqueued for execution before they are removed by one of the handlers.

Comment: Case in point: `e.on('a', x=> {e.removeAllListeners('a'); e.on('a', y => console.log('y = ' + y);); console.log('x = ' + x);}); e.emit('a', 0); e.emit('a', 1);` - certainly, removing listeners had immediate effect, but not so for adding a listener - the second listener does not receive event 0, so not everything has immediate effect.

Comment: That's a different scenario. If you're adding/removing listeners for a particular event from *within* an event handler for that same event, then it will not take effect until the next `emit()` for that particular event. `emit()` makes a copy of the event listeners first in order to prevent various issues including cycles/loops. Even with this, there is still no explicit deferring until the next tick or later in any of the `EventEmitter` functions.

Comment: Now that you mention that it takes a copy of the event listeners, we are back to the original question. :-) What does EventEmitter guarantee to happen with the "original list", what it guarantees to happen with a new list, and what it does not guarantee. For example, adding more event listeners to `e` shows that `e.removeAllListeners` is not immediate, contrary to what you said in the answer. It, indeed, behaves like EventEmitter took a copy of the list of event listeners.

Comment: It creates a copy no matter what. My point is that the end result depends on the situation. In your original example, you were removing listeners for one event from an event handler for another event. In that case there is absolutely no problem at all. In the different example you just gave here in the comments, there could be a potential "issue" since it's the *same* event. My answer still stands as I said: there is no `process.nextTick()`, `setImmediate()`, or similar calls inside `EventEmitter` methods, so there is no deferring in that sense.

Comment: Well, the difference in the case I gave in the original post is that you _don't know_ whether it will end up triggering or manipulating the same event, and in the example here in comments it is made obvious. Anyway, thanks for the answer.